# Error al escanear números con decimales

Tags: java

Al escanear o tomar un número con decimales como 1,5 por ejemplo devuelve error. ¿Qué sucede?

```
    System.out.print("\nIntroduce la tasa de interés (%): ");
    Scanner teclado2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double tasa = teclado2.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(tasa);
```

Error:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at MyClass.interesesYNuevoCapital(MyClass.java:49)
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:6)

Comment: proba con 1.5 en vez de 1,5

Comment: Así funciona. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alderson te sucedió un error muy común al utilizar `Scanner`, estas ingresando el numero decimal con una coma y no con un punto `(1,5 / 1.5)` y es por eso que no te lo toma como un parametro `double` válido, lanzando así la `InputMismatchException`.

Si deseas poder ingresar con coma te recomiendo lo siguiente:

```
String input= scan.nextLine();

input= input.replace(",", ".");

double result = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

> nextDouble() usa los puntos decimales y separadores de miles propios del idioma. Si queres usar la coma, se puede modificar el idioma de Scanner asi.

```
   Scanner teclado2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    teclado2.useLocale(Locale.ITALIAN);
```

> Si queres que el separador decimal sea un punto, lo configuras asi.

```
  Scanner teclado2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    teclado2.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```